# strongSelf pointing to weakSelf in a block, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to understand this code :

```
__weak LoginViewController *weakSelf = self;

NSTimer *networkTimer = [NSTimer pym_scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 block:^{
    LoginViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf timeout];
} repeats:NO];

[PYMAuthManager loginWithUsername:username password:password completionHandler:^(BOOL successful) {
    if (successful) {
        [networkTimer invalidate].......
```

it's for a network timer, that will timeout after 15 seconds if no activity. Why is the pointer *strongSelf = weakSelf created in the block? Is it not okay just to use [weakSelf timeout]? I understood that whenever accessing self in a block we have to use a weak reference, why is another pointer created here? Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Turn warnings on, and the compiler will tell you. And you can't just learn simple rules, you need to understand what a weak reference is for these rules to be applied _intelligently_ and for them to make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated to better reflect actual system semantics (as pointed out by Darren).

By using `weakSelf` in the block, you are avoiding retain cycles. If you were to replace the block code with `[weakSelf timeout]`, there would be no difference; the object is retained for the duration of the `timeout` execution.

If you had instead used `__unsafe_unretained` to create your `weakSelf`, it's possible that the machine could release the memory back to the system and cause your app to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while executing `timeout`. Creating a strong reference in this instance would avoid this error.

---

When you create a strong reference, it is held within its scope; in this case, for the duration of the block. Because your block only effectively executes one statement, the replacement to `[weakSelf timeout]` causes no harm. If you had multiple statements that all used `weakSelf` or relied on the state of `weakSelf`, then you would want to create a strong reference for the scope of all of the statements.

Comment: However, in this particular example there's no need to do that because sending a `timeout` message to `nil` would be harmless.

Comment: The issue isn't that `weakSelf` might be `nil` before `timeout` is called; it's that might be made `nil` *during* `timeout`'s execution.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's the case with `__unsafe_unretained` references but actually isn't true with `__weak` references.  Calling a method on a `__weak` reference automatically retains that object for the duration of the method, so in this example the conversion to a strong reference is completely superfluous (but harmless).  See: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id23

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know there was a difference. Thanks for the link; that's a nice reference.

Comment: "By using weakSelf in the block, you are avoiding retain cycles." There is actually no evidence that there would be a retain cycle here.

Comment: @newacct: I was speaking generally in that sentence.